# Variadic template and overwriting

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, overwrite

I am wondering whether it is somehow possible to overwrite a method in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename P, typename ...Keys>
class Object {
public:
    void method1(P p, Keys... keys) {
        method2(std::make_tuple(keys...), p);
    }

    void method2(const std::tuple<Keys...> my_tuple, int id) {
        printf("Hello1!");
    }
};

class MyObject : public Object<int, char, char> {
public:
    void method2(const std::tuple<int, char> my_tuple, int id) {
        printf("Hello2!");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MyObject obj;
    int a = 13;
    obj.method1(a, 'a', 'c'); // prints Hello1! and not Hello2!
}
```

This code prints 'Hello1'. I want it to print 'Hello2'.

If I change method2 into

```
abstract void method2(const std::tuple<Keys...> my_tuple, int id) = 0;
```

I get the following error:

error: cannot declare variable 'obj' to be of abstract type 'MyObject' obj;
main.cpp:16:7: note:because the following virtual functions are pure within 'MyObject':

What is the correct way to overwrite method2 in MyObject?

Best,
Moritz

Comment: The error you posted is about a `virtual` function but your code has none.

Comment: As, I mentioned, "Even, if I change method2 into a virtual function...". Without the virtual function, it just prints "Hello1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `MyObject` derives from `Object<int, char, char>` which means `P=char` and `Keys=<char, char>`, but you override `method2` with `Keys=<int, char>`.  Either derive from `Object<int, int, char>` or change `MyObject::method2` to take `tuple<char, char>`.

You *also* need `method2` to be virtual, as you have already tried.  With the above fix, it won't cause a "cannot declare" error anymore.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the small example. But in my actual program, the whole thing does not work. I will try to provide a minimum example that produces the same error: "expansion pattern '...' contains no argument packs".